# django change password form not raising error

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have a form for changing password:

```
class PasswordChangeForm(forms.Form):
old_password = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
new_password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
new_password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    super(PasswordChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_old_password(self):
    old_password = self.cleaned_data.get("old_password")

    if not self.user.check_password(old_password):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Your old password is wrong")
    return old_password

def clean_new_password2(self):
    new_password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("new_password1")
    new_password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("new_password2")
    if new_password1 and new_password2 and new_password1 != new_password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Your new passwords didn't match")
    return new_password2
```

In my view I have:

```
class PasswordChangeView(View):
form_class = PasswordChangeForm
template_name = 'registration/password_change.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(user=self.request.user)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    print("wow")
    if form.is_valid():
        #My logic here
        return redirect("password_change_successful")
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

But my form.is_valid() function is not called.. Even if i enter wrong old password or wrong new passwords it doesnot raise error.

What is wrong in here ??
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure why you're defining any of this yourself. Django already includes [forms and views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) for precisely this functionality, all you have to do is provide the templates and link them to URLs.

Comment: What if i want to do this way ?? is there any way ??

Comment: Of course there is. But look at how you've overridden the signature of the form, and then look at how you're instantiating it in the `post` method. And I would say that even if you don't want to use the supplied auth stuff, you should at the very least use the appropriate classes for what you are doing: you should use a ModelForm and an UpdateView.

Comment: can you please elaborate it in answer..

Comment: I am writing this for an api so i dont want to use update view.. Can i do this with view ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are misusing class-based views.
Your view should inherit from `FormView`, not from simple `View`.
And it should have a method with signature `form_valid(self, form)`, which will be called as soon as a valid form has been submitted.
Also, you don't need to override get and post methods. In fact, it is not very good idea to do so.
I apologize for the criticism.
Here is how your view should look like:

```
class PasswordChangeView(FormView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = reverse("password_change_successful")  # if form had no errors, FormView redirects to this url
    template_name = 'registration/password_change.html'

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
    # print "wow"
    logger.debug("Wow, some user has sent a valid form!")
    return super(PasswordChangeView, self).form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)

    # def get(...)
    # there is really no need to override get(), FormView will do everything for you 

    # def post(...)
    # same story with the post, if your form was valid,
    # form_valid() will be called, otherwise user will stay on the
    # same page, with the same form displaying the validation errors
```